# Is there a way to monitor who downloads a python app from pypi and what functions are being instrumented?

Tags: python, pypi, telemetry

I am looking to instrument something like telemetry in my open source package so I can monitor how often it is being used and what functions are the most useful

of course this would be opt-in for the user if possible

Comment: Sure, you can write telemetry into anything. But I would be very, very cautious about doing this. Most people don't like to be spied on. I can't imagine who would voluntarily turn this "feature" on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.